# Virtual machine increase disk space and reached at low disk space issue

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, disk, diskspace, ambari

I have installed `Apache Amabari` on three `VM` cluster system before 1 month ago and utilized something 47 GB out of 183 GB but now it has been increasing daily 1 to 2 GB not installed any other thing. Could you guild me how can I need to remove or free space from VM.

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                      490G   22G  444G   5% /
tmpfs                 3.9G  8.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   48M  404M  11% /boot
vagrant               183G  181G  2.3G  99% /vagrant

VM 1 take 49 GB Space Used
VM 2 take 29 GB Space Used
VM 3 take 79 GB Space Used
```

VM 3 root Level file Space Details

```
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root    root          4096 May 12 08:05 bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root    root          1024 Apr 27  2013 boot
drwxr-xr-x    3 root    root          4096 May 12 08:40 cgroups_test
drwxr-xr-x   18 root    root          3680 Jun 14 10:37 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 102 root    root          4096 Jun 14 10:37 etc
drwxr-xr-x    5 root    root          4096 May 12 10:11 hadoop
drwxr-xr-x.  19 root    root          4096 May 22 08:39 home
dr-xr-xr-x.   9 root    root          4096 May 12 08:05 lib
dr-xr-xr-x.  10 root    root         12288 May 12 08:05 lib64
drwx------.   2 root    root         16384 Apr 27  2013 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root    root          4096 Apr 27  2013 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root    root          4096 Sep 23  2011 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root    root          4096 Apr 27  2013 opt
dr-xr-xr-x  111 root    root             0 Jun 14 10:37 proc
dr-xr-x---.   5 root    root          4096 Jun 13 13:28 root
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root    root         12288 May 12 08:05 sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root    root          4096 Apr 27  2013 selinux
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root    root          4096 Sep 23  2011 srv
-rw-r--r--    1 root    root    3221225472 Jun 14 10:38 swapfile
drwxr-xr-x   13 root    root             0 Jun 14 10:37 sys
drwxrwxrwt.  42 root    root          4096 Jun 16 06:53 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.  15 root    root          4096 May 12 08:04 usr
drwxr-xr-x    1 vagrant vagrant       4096 May 12 05:44 vagrant
drwxr-xr-x.  19 root    root          4096 May 17 07:48 var
[root@c6403 /]# pwd
/
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong or please tell me how can I increse free space from my VM.

Comment: Have you looked in the VMs to see where the file space is being used?

Comment: @DaveS Please check I have added VM 3 disk space information. I have created snapshot before fews days ago but after I reached disk space issue I have removed that one from here. But I am getting again this issue. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to say is that Ambari Vagrant environment is **not intended** for production use. This configuration should be used for study and/or testing. Running Hadoop cluster on virtual machines on a single physical host imposes major performance and reliability drawbacks (e.g. implicitly broken failover/data replication). For details, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344195/which-one-is-best-apache-ambari-cluster-on-physical-system-with-5-machine-or-in)

*For production use*, you should either install Ambari directly on a physical machine or provision 1-2 virtual machines per every physical host of your cluster.

If you are still going to stay with virtual machines and dig into troubleshooting, try installing [ncdu](https://techglimpse.com/install-ncdu-centos-linux-tutorial/) utility into your VM.

The typical `ncdu` output looks like:

```
ncdu 1.7 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help                                                         
--- /data ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  163.3GiB [##########] /docimages                                                                                  
   84.4GiB [#####     ] /data
   82.0GiB [#####     ] /sldata
   56.2GiB [###       ] /prt
   40.1GiB [##        ] /slisam
   30.8GiB [#         ] /isam
   18.3GiB [#         ] /mail
   10.2GiB [          ] /export
    3.9GiB [          ] /edi   
    1.7GiB [          ] /io     
    1.2GiB [          ] /dmt
  896.7MiB [          ] /src
  821.5MiB [          ] /upload
  691.1MiB [          ] /client
  686.8MiB [          ] /cocoon
  542.5MiB [          ] /hist
  358.1MiB [          ] /savsrc
  228.9MiB [          ] /help
  108.1MiB [          ] /savbin
  101.2MiB [          ] /dm
   40.7MiB [          ] /download
```

Similar output (but without sorting), may be achieved by runing this command:

```
du -sh /*
```

This way you can see what takes the most space in your virtual machine. Probably most space is taken up by logs at `/var/log/`. Also, explore `/usr/hdp` directory using `ncdu`, because a lot of HDP stack files are stored here

Comment: Could explain me why swapfile getting more space. Please check above as I mentioned above. -rw-r--r--    1 root    root    3221225472 Jun 14 10:38 swapfile

Comment: probably you have insufficient amount of RAM for your workload. Try increasing memory allocated to VM

Comment: I have 64 GB RAM of Machine. I think this one not cause.

Comment: what `free -m` says?

Comment: total  |used|free|shared|buffers|cachedMem: 64171|56641|7529|0|233|28504
-/+ buffers/cache:      27903/36268
Swap:          766          0        766

Comment: That's an output from host VM. What `free -m` says inside VM?